# How to resolve error: "The post’s action links must be valid URLs"

Tags: facebook, sharekit

Using the latest version of ShareKit to post URLs like so:

```
[SHKFacebook shareURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

is resulting in the following error message being displayed (in a web view):

```
Application response error
The post’s action links must be valid URLs. You can see this because you are one of the developers of the app.
```

What does this error message really mean, and (more importantly) how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem occurs if 'SHKConfigMyAppURL' is not a valid URL.

Comment: Well, what constitutes a valid URL? The google URL in the example your provided looks like a valid URL to me.

Comment: In this case it was the application's URL that was invalid (NOT the URL being shared)